# How to split multiple datas from multiple lines in perl

Tags: perl

Firstly, I have the data below:

```
*********************************************************************
TEST CASE 
*********************************************************************
test results for the last 1 run(s)

 TEST                      TITLE                                    GROUP    PRIO R-STAT R-TIME       VERDICT  VERDICT-TEXT
 ------------------------- ---------------------------------------- -------- ---- ------ ------------ -------- --------------------------------------------------
 TESTCASE1            TC1                            ABC     1    PASS   00:00:09.572 PASS     nothing

TESTCASE2            TC2          DEF     2    PASS   00:00:01.650 PASS     nothing


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NUMBER OF : 2
NUMBER OF TC: 2
*********************************************************************
VERDICT: PASS
*********************************************************************
```

I would like to perform lines:

```
TESTCASE1            TC1                            ABC     1    PASS   00:00:09.572 PASS     nothing

TESTCASE2            TC2          DEF     2    PASS   00:00:01.650 PASS     nothing
```

and split first lines and last lines.

How can I do that?

ADDITIONAL:

Sorry for too late reply, i want to split

```
*********************************************************************
TEST CASE 
*********************************************************************
test results for the last 1 run(s)

 TEST                      TITLE                                    GROUP    PRIO R-STAT R-TIME       VERDICT  VERDICT-TEXT
 ------------------------- ---------------------------------------- -------- ---- ------ ------------ -------- --------------------------------------------------
```

just handled two lines

```
TESTCASE1            TC1                            ABC     1    PASS   00:00:09.572 PASS     nothing

TESTCASE2            TC2          DEF     2    PASS   00:00:01.650 PASS     nothing
i use while loop to check line by line, the problem is it will be looped all of lines whereas i want two lines only.
```

Comment: It isn't very clear to me what you are trying to do. Can you explain it any better ?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "perform"?  I would loop over each line and do a regex match for "TESTCASE".

Comment: Are you wanting to split the TEST and VERDICT-TEXT fields on these lines?

Comment: please see my edit above, i am sorry because i reply too late

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get first and last line from file:

```
cat filename | grep "^TESTCASE" | sed -n '1p;$p'
```

Comment: cat command seems not in lib Perl, could you please help to point the same command in perl?

Comment: @nguyenthanh the `cat` command is a unix shell command.  user1244533, one need not `cat file | grep pattern`, one can just `grep pattern file` instead.  Saves a little bit on the shell.